# Keeping a value after loop

Tags: c++

Basically I'm generating the skeleton of a poker game. I'm simply trying to get the betting system down. What I have stumbled upon in my code is that the values of my int's keep reverting back to their original state (100). I'm obviously doing something wrong, and that is my question (what am I doing wrong, and what can I do to fix it).

```
class BetSys
{
public:
    int loseM;
    int bet;
    int earn;
    int money;
    int Tmoney;
    int Omoney;
    void Loop();
    void Flow();
    void Game();

};

void BetSys::Loop()
{
int Omoney = 100;
int bet = 0;
int loseM = 0;
loseM = loseM + bet;
cout << "Your start money = " << Omoney << " \n\n\n" << endl;
Game();

}

void BetSys::Game()
{
bool win;
bool lose;
int Omoney = 100;
int* PointMon = &Omoney;
int money = 0;
int Tmoney = 0;
int bet = 0;
int earn = (bet * 2) + *PointMon;
int loseM = 0;
cout << "Place your bet here!" << endl;
cin >> bet;


money = *PointMon - bet;
cout << "Your total money after bet is " << money << "\n\n";


//betP(int money)
//{
//  money - bet = money;
//}
if (bet > 10)
{
    win = true;
    if (win)
    {
        cout << "YOU WIN! \n\n" << endl;
        /*earn = (earn) + Omoney;*/
        cout << "You earned: \n" << earn;
        Tmoney = earn + (*PointMon - bet);
        cout << "\nTotal money: \n" << Tmoney;
    }
}
else if (bet <= 10)
{
    lose = true;
    if (lose)
    {
        cout << "You Lose!\n\n\n" << endl;
        int Mlose= loseM + bet;
        cout << "You lost: \n" << Mlose;
        Tmoney = loseM + (*PointMon - bet);
        cout << "\nTotal money: \n" << Tmoney;
        cout << "\n\n\n\n";
        *PointMon = Tmoney;
        //for(int i = 0, i > 20, i++)
        //{
        //  int i=10;
        //}
        Flow();

    }
}
}
void BetSys::Flow()
{
Game();
}
```

Comment: Where is what wrong, and what is your output?

Comment: Just skimming the code, there are a lot of weirdnesses. For instance, your use of pointers makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: What is the purpose of `Pointmon`?  Why not just reference `Omoney` directly?

Comment: I appreciate the honesty, but I do not need opinions on my code. It's not done yet - why it looks weird. I'm also a student in an intro to C++ class so I'm not a pro yet at this, trying to learn (why I'm on here :P ). Anyways, the pointer is to reference the value of Omoney(I set it to 100 right now, but it could be any value when the program is done), and I need whatever value that is (omoney) to equal a new value (PointMon) so the program knows how much the start money was, without affecting the original Omoney value.

Comment: @AartStuurman my output is not the problem. What's wrong is when the it goes to Loop(), then back to Game() PointMon goes back to 100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `int Omoney` declared as class member and as local variable in `BetSys::Game()` and `BetSys::Loop()`. Your local ones are hiding the class member.

You need to remove them. Init the class member in the constructor using an initializer list.

**EDIT**

Add an explicit public constructor to you class

```
...
void Flow();
void Game();
BetSys();
```

an define it like this:

```
BetSys::BetSys() : Omoney(100) {
    cout << "Omoney inited to " << Omoney << endl;
}
```

When you create an instance of that class `Omoney inited to 100` will be printed!

Comment: In addition to this, please look into your use of pointers. They seem odd and unneeded to me.

Comment: So I just need to put a public in front of them?

Comment: @Eeeearth, No remove them completely, you already have declared it in the public section of your class, so it will be visible inside/accessible the methods of the class!

Comment: @A4L But I can't initialize the datatype there though?